# Spark Streaming is killed every after 2 hours

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

Spark Streaming Application is killed every after 2 hours withoud any logs when I checked worker logs and found the following error:

```
14/11/15 13:53:24 INFO network.ConnectionManager: Removing ReceivingConnection to ConnectionManagerId(ip-xxxxxxxxx,38863)
14/11/15 13:53:24 INFO network.ConnectionManager: Removing SendingConnection to ConnectionManagerId(ip-xxxxxxxxx,38863)
14/11/15 13:53:24 ERROR network.SendingConnection: Exception while reading SendingConnection to ConnectionManagerI
```

I have also set the spark.cleaner.ttl value to 10 min but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the stream receiver is stopped.
do you use something like this in your code?
    streamContext.stop(true, true);

If the stream receiver is stopped and you are listening to the receiver then the context will stop too.

Comment: No I have not called stop method